# How to copy to clipboard in Vim 8.1?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, clipboard

Is it possible that this vim version does not support clipboard functionalities?

I've asked ChatGPT and apparently this version does not support the clipboard, but is there a way to solve this? Maybe a plugin?.

When I try `"+y` or `"*y`, it says "X lines yanked" and then if I press `p` I can paste into Vim, but can't paste it outside Vim.

When prompting `:set clipboard?` output is: "Option not supported"

Comment: Real Ubuntu? Server Linux? WSL or WSL2? Tried something from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clipboard+vim+ubuntu ?

Comment: Type `:version` to see which options are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Vim can be built with or without a number of features. Clipboard support is one of those features and neither the Vim that is installed by default on your system nor the Vim package provided by your package manager are built with it.

If you use X11 and you want a Vim built with clipboard support, you can simply install the "vim-gtk" or "vim-gtk3" package.